# Nothing I've been trying seems to get the Magnific Popup to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I've spent a lot of time trying to get this Magnific Popup thing to work locally on my website, and it keeps linking me to a separate image page, instead of getting the popup viewer I wanted.

Does anyone know where my errors are and how I can get it to work?

I'm kind of new to jQuery, so I'm kinda clueless as to why this code is not working.

Edit: Is there something I need to download to get it to work?

All three source codes are in my folder, and I did check to see if they are at the right links, and I'm still not getting any of the Magnific popups.

This is what I have in my document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="website.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="my_jquery.js"></script>
<title> Name </title>



        <link href="magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="singleimage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">







 </head>
  <body>

<div id="navigation">
    <div id="header_left"><span id="header_text1">Name</span> </div>

    <div id="header_right"> <span id="header_text2">
    <a href="#home">Link</a>
    <a href="#name">Link</a>
    <a href="#name">Link</a>
    <a href="#name">Link</a>
    <a href="#name">Link</a> 
     </span> </div>

</div>






<a name="graphicdesign">
<div class="bg-image2">

    <div class="test1">
        <div class="test2"> <h1>Page Title</h1>


<a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="cat_b.jpg" title="Caption. Can be aligned it to any side and contain any HTML.">
<img src="cat_s.jpg " width="75" height="75">
</a>
<a class="image-popup-fit-width" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_b.jpg" title="This image fits only horizontally.">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
</a>
<a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg">
<img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" width="107" height="75">
</a>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
    });






    $(document).ready(function() {

$('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    image: {
        verticalFit: true
    }

});

$('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    image: {
        verticalFit: false
    }
});

$('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: false,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
    image: {
        verticalFit: true
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
    } }); });
    </script>



    <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->



        </div>
    </div>
</div> </a>
```

I've been getting three errors from the code I pasted from Magnific Popup. I didn't change the code in any way, and I still ended up with errors. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to change it somehow or not. I'm puzzled on what to do.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index_01.html:73

Here are some of the codes around lines 75 on that page:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
    });
```

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4

```
    (function(e){var t,n,i,o,r,a,s,l="Close",c="BeforeClose",d="AfterClose",u="BeforeAppend",p=
```

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.magnific-popup.js:38

```
     _window = $(window),
```

Comment: First of all, since this is a jQuery plugin, you should add a link to it _after_ link to jQuery.min.js. Another thing - you can combine all your script blocks in one, it would be a lot easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I was wondering how I could fix the weird indents... xD

Answer (score 2):

Well, as I pointed out in comments, you should add link to magnific-popup.js after jQuery, since this is a plugin:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

I've created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3j89/), is this what you wanted (looks kind of creepy)? I also combined all your script in one block like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        delegate: 'a',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        }
    });
    $('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
        type: 'image'
        // other options
    });
    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        }

    });

    $('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        image: {
            verticalFit: false
        }
    });

    $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        closeBtnInside: false,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from                left and right side
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Oooh so I should have magnific-popup.js link at the very bottom of my body section? Ive tried opening the jsfiddle thing you tried, but for some reason it didnt load for me. I'm not sure if I combined too many jquery codes on my page. I ended up adding more jquery codes on after I find that one doesn't work...

Comment: Since your script is inside `$(document).ready()` function, it doesn't matter, where you put links to your scripts. It does matter though the order of script links. What do you mean it didn't load? You can't open jsfiddle?

Comment: Nevermind xD the jsfiddle didn't load for me earlier, but now it works! I'm very confused now, it looks like the popups are working in jsfiddle....? But when I try the codes locally, the popups didnt even work!

do I need to download something to make jquery codes work locally because I'm not getting the same results : (

Comment: Do you have jQuery and magnific popup scripts in the same folder as your html? Basically you should put them in some folder with other scripts and on html page then you should point to their location (by including `<script>` tags) relatively to this page.

Comment: The files are in the same folder in my HTML, and I checked the file links 5 times already to see if they have the right names and I still am not getting any popups : (

I'm not sure why its not working...

Comment: I seem to have 4 errors:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
/my_jquery.js:12

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
index_01.html:73

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: This means that jquery is not loader on your page. Are you sure jquery is loaded to your page and is loaded before your script?

Comment: My bad, ignore the first error (my_jquery.js)... it wasn't part of the magnific-popup codes. I would like to work on getting the magnific-popup jquery files to work somehow....