# Zoom in cursor not working with Magnific Popup

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

Although I have absolutely zero ability with JavaScript I was able to get the Magnific Popup plugin to work via this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3j89/) from this [previous Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153559/nothing-ive-been-trying-seems-to-get-the-magnific-popup-to-work-properly). However, the zoom in cursor doesn't appear but rather the hand pointer does. I've tried a few methods but can't seem to get it to work properly. Any solutions on what's missing in the code? (And no, I am not using IE. I'm using Firefox and realize that the zoom in cursor doesn't even work on the Magnific Popup homepage with IE, an issue IE has with CSS3 from what I gather.)

(As well, I did try adding a comment to the original Stack Overflow post, but as I don't have 50 reputation points I was unable to do so and so am creating this new question.)

Thanks in advance.

```
<a name="nameA">
<div class="nameB">

    <div class="test1">
        <div class="test2">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>

            <a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="cat.jpg" title="Caption. Can be aligned it to any side and contain any HTML.">
                <img src="cat.jpg" width="75" height="75">
            </a>
            <a class="image-popup-fit-width" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_b.jpg" title="This image fits only horizontally.">
                <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_s.jpg" width="75" height="75">
            </a>
            <a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg">
                <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" width="107" height="75">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
$('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    delegate: 'a',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    image: {
        verticalFit: true
    }
});
$('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
    type: 'image'
    // other options
});
$('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    image: {
        verticalFit: true
    }

});

$('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    image: {
        verticalFit: false
    }
});

$('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: false,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from                left and right side
    image: {
        verticalFit: true
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
    }
});
```

});

Comment: magnific-popup has css you are supposed to add, that fiddle didn't have it. The hand is in that css as well as other required styles.

Comment: @Christina: I think you mean "the magnifying glass is in that css." Regardless, I do have the css and js files required for Magnific Popup in working order (as the popups otherwise wouldn't be working I take it). I too figured it should all work fine, but for whatever reason it doesn't. So I rigged a solution together as seen below in my reply to dngege's answer. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Yes, the magnifying icon, however the css is missing from the fiddle you linked to. Magnific Popup does work without the css but it looks strange. It works to a point, if you don't actually use the css that the developer provides there will issues on touch devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a CSS snippet like this:

```
a { cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;  cursor: zoom-in; }
```

Comment: I'd seen that code in my searches (I'm a newbie), but didn't try it as I figured it would change the cursor for everything. Anyway, I tried it, and it changed the cursor for everything. So I instead created a new class and just added it to every instance where it's needed. Not the cleanest way to do it, but a viable workaround. Thanks.