# How do I add a caption with an HTML link to a Magnific Popup image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I'd like to get an HTML caption (with a link) under a Magnific Popup image but can't seem to get it done (I presume this is possible since it's described on the Magnific Popup site). As of now I can include some text inline via title="This is a caption", but I obviously can't put HTML in there.

From what I gather from other Stack Overflow posts, you include something like this:

```
titleSrc: function(item){
    return item.el.find('p').text()
}
```

and then put your HTML code in P tags, but when I insert that piece of code into my Javascript the Magnific Popup functionality disappears and the image just becomes a regular link.

This is the HTML I'm currently using:

```
<figure>
    <a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="image.png" title="This is a non-HTML caption">
        <img src="image-small.png">
    </a>
</figure>
```

And this is the Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            delegate: 'a',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
            image: {
                verticalFit: true
            }
        });
        $('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
            type: 'image'
            // other options
        });
        $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
            image: {
                verticalFit: true
            }

        });

        $('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            image: {
                verticalFit: false
            }
        });

        $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            closeBtnInside: false,
            fixedContentPos: true,
            mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
            image: {
                verticalFit: true
            },
            zoom: {
                enabled: true,
                duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't know if the Javascript is bloated or not, but it's what I got from a [previous Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153559/nothing-ive-been-trying-seems-to-get-the-magnific-popup-to-work-properly), seeing how I know nothing about Javascript. If it makes any difference, I do have more than one Popup working on the same page.

Thanks for any help.

p.s. If this is in fact possible, could one then just center the HTML caption with CSS?